# reactive plots sidebars and tabs

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, sidebar, reactive

I'm trying to build a shiny app that has multiple tabs that pull from the same data that I filter down with radio buttons and selectizeInput in the sidebar.

You could generate the data for the first heat map with the following code:

```
dat<-expand.grid(2:6,7:20,letters[1:8],LETTERS[1:26])
dat$Var5<-sample(0:200,nrow(dat),replace = T)
names(dat)<-c("WEEKDAY"  ,
              "HOUR"   ,
              "MEETING_LOCATION" ,
              "COURSE_SUBJECT",
              "n.SESSIONS")
dat[,"WEEKDAY"]<-factor(dat[,1],levels = c("2","3","4","5","6"),ordered = T)
dat[,c("MEETING_LOCATION","COURSE_SUBJECT")]<-lapply(dat[,c("MEETING_LOCATION","COURSE_SUBJECT")],as.character)
```

I can get the interface to show up, but a lot of examples I'm finding on stack don't make it very clear how I need to wrap all the functions, and I know I'm almost there with this first one.

The shiny app code I'm using looks a lot like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Oh My God Please Help"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             h4("Filter"),
             radioButtons("MEETING_LOCATION",
                          "Location:",
                          c("a" = "a",
                            "b" = "b",
                            "c" = "c",
                            "d" = "d",
                            "e" = "e",
                            "f" = "f",
                            "g" = "g",
                            "h" = "h")),
             selectizeInput("COURSE_SUBJECT",
                                         label = "Course Subject: ",
                                         choices = LETTERS[1:26],
                                         selected = NULL,
                                         multiple = T)
             ))
    ))


  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("Usage",plotOutput("USAGE")))
    # other tabs I need to put in don't pay attention to this
    # other tabs I need to put in don't pay attention to this
    # other tabs I need to put in don't pay attention to this
  )


  server <- function(input, output) {


    usage.0<-reactive({
      dat%>%
        dplyr::filter(COURSE_SUBJECT %in% input$COURSE_SUBJECT)%>%
        dplyr::filter(MEETING_LOCATION==input$MEETING_LOCATION)%>%
        group_by(WEEKDAY,HOUR)%>%
        sumarise(TOTAL.SESSIONS = sum(n.SESSIONS))
    })
    output$USAGE <- renderPlot({
      usage.0()%>%
        ggplot(aes(x = WEEKDAY,y = HOUR))+
        geom_tile(aes(fill = TOTAL.SESSIONS))+
        geom_text(aes(label = TOTAL.SESSIONS),colour = "white",fontface = "bold",size = 3)+
        scale_fill_gradient(guide = guide_legend(title = "Total Number of\nMeetings"),low = "#00ABE1",high = "#FFCD00")+
        theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
              legend.background = element_blank(), 
              legend.key = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank(),
              axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 35, hjust = 1),
              panel.border = element_blank(),
              strip.background = element_blank(), 
              plot.background = element_blank())+
        xlab("Weekday")+
        ylab("Hour")+
        ggtitle("Busiest Tutoring Days/Hours")
    })
  }

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think the problem has to do with how/where I'm (not)rendering the plot. maybe I need to actually have another tab so R knows what to do, I don't know... I do know this is probably really inefficient code, so any help there would be great, but the main focus is just to get this heat map to show up when I select the data's subset from the sidebar/radio buttons.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems that I see here.

1) Your `fluidPage` is closed `)` before you include the mainPanel. A trick to identifying this is a) your stuff doesn't show up. Or b) Reindent lines in the code menu. If they don't line up you know something is wrong.

2) I strongly recommend that you write your data preparation and plots as functions that you can test outside of the context of your app. Then use the functions in the app. I've done so below. This gives you the ability to test them independently of the application (no Run App, reload, rinse, repeat slowdowns). This makes your app much cleaner and easier to navigate when you're editing UI/Server elements. As well as make growth and testing more sane.

3) In your code, never ever use numeric references to columns (like `dat[,1]`). Always use the name of the column. It takes slightly more time but saves you when the data changes in the future and saves someone else when reading your code.

4) When posting code, please test to see if it actually works for yourself. Line by line! If you look at the result of `dat` you might be surprised by what you find.

Your job now, fix the functions so that they do what you expect them to.

app.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Oh My God Please Help"),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        h4("Filter"),
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "MEETING_LOCATION",
          "Location:",
          c("a" = "a",
            "b" = "b",
            "c" = "c",
            "d" = "d",
            "e" = "e",
            "f" = "f",
            "g" = "g",
            "h" = "h")),
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = "COURSE_SUBJECT",
          label = "Course Subject: ",
          choices = LETTERS[1:26],
          selected = NULL,
          multiple = T)
      ))
  ),
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Usage",
        plotOutput("USAGE")
    )
  ) # Don't forget the comma here! , 
  # other tabs I need to put in don't pay attention to this
  # other tabs I need to put in don't pay attention to this
  # other tabs I need to put in don't pay attention to this
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  usage_prep <- reactive({
    cat(input$MEETING_LOCATION)
    cat(input$COURSE_SUBJECT)

    myData(dat, input$MEETING_LOCATION, input$COURSE_SUBJECT)

  })

  output$USAGE <- renderPlot({
    myPlot(usage_prep())
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

global.R

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat<-expand.grid(2:6,7:20,letters[1:8],LETTERS[1:26])
dat$Var5<-sample(0:200,nrow(dat),replace = T)
names(dat)<-c("WEEKDAY"  ,
              "HOUR"   ,
              "MEETING_LOCATION" ,
              "COURSE_SUBJECT",
              "n.SESSIONS")
dat$WEEKDAY <-factor(dat$WEEKDAY,levels = c("2","3","4","5","6"),ordered = T)



myData <- function(dat, meeting_location, course_subject) {
  dat %>%
    filter(COURSE_SUBJECT %in% course_subject)%>%
    filter(MEETING_LOCATION==meeting_location)%>%
    group_by(WEEKDAY,HOUR)%>%
    summarise(TOTAL.SESSIONS = sum(n.SESSIONS))
}

myPlot <- function(pd) {
  ggplot(pd, aes(x = WEEKDAY,y = HOUR))+
    geom_tile(aes(fill = TOTAL.SESSIONS))+
    geom_text(aes(label = TOTAL.SESSIONS),colour = "white",fontface = "bold",size = 3)+
    scale_fill_gradient(guide = guide_legend(title = "Total Number of\nMeetings"),low = "#00ABE1",high = "#FFCD00")+
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          legend.background = element_blank(),
          legend.key = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 35, hjust = 1),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          plot.background = element_blank())+
    xlab("Weekday")+
    ylab("Hour")+
    ggtitle("Busiest Tutoring Days/Hours")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response. I really appreciate the pointers on code cleaning. I can’t wait to get to that when my mind is fresh

Comment: Brandon Bertelsen I looked through my code and I can see how messy it was, and how keeping it more organized can save a lot of headache. Thanks again for the pointers. If I could upvote your answer 100 times I would!